# How to write blocks of code

Tags: support, code-block

I really hope someone out there could help me understand my doubt regarding posting/answering with a code block on Stack Overflow.

OK, so I posted the below R function a while back, and as you can see it's long; it takes 10 lines. I know the post directions say to indent four times to format code. This took me a while when I did it because when I copied and pasted the function from the R script to the post I had to indent each line four times, which was a lot and obviously didn't like it.

I now know I can also use back ticks in the beginning and in the end of a code block and it would produce the same result as if I were to manually indent each line of the function four times. But there has to be a difference. No? Can I just always use back ticks when trying to format a long code block like the following function?

`CV_concentration <- function(x,cv.tol.raw,A,B,C,D){
 y_at_x <- (A-D)/(1+(x/C)^B)+D
 y_low <- y_at_x * (1-cv.tol.raw/sqrt(2))
 y_high <- y_at_x * (1+cv.tol.raw/sqrt(2))
 x_at_ylow <- C*((A-D)/(y_low-D)-1)^(1/B)
 x_at_yhigh <- C*((A-D)/(y_high-D)-1)^(1/B)
 x_range <- c(x_at_ylow, x_at_yhigh)
 cv_con <- sd(x_range)/mean(x_range)
 return(cv_con)
 }`

Comment: There is a way to do this automatically in the editor itself. It's explained in the FAQ here: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always faced this issue, and a simple solution was I used to indent the code in any of the editors I was using and copy paste it until I found the shortcut.

```
command + k
```

This is for OS X, and it should be replaced with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>. Copy the lines while editing the question and use this shortcut.